# variable text in virtual environment

Tags: environments

I have this MWE which works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{example}
\counterwithin*{example}{section}
\newenvironment{example}[1][]{%
    \stepcounter{example}%
    \par\vspace{5pt}\noindent
    \fbox{\textbf{Example~\thesection.\theexample}}%
    \hrulefill\par\vspace{10pt}\noindent\rmfamily}%
{\par\noindent\hrulefill\vrule}
\begin{document}
\section{First section}
Some introductory text...
\begin{example}
    \begin{equation}
        f(x)=\frac{x}{1+x^2}
    \end{equation}
\end{example}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But how do I add variable example title?

Comment: edited and fixed.
The optional argument should be, I think, next to \begin{example} but I am not sure if that is possible?

Comment: you have already declared an optional argument so you can have `\begin{example}[title]` but you do not use `#1`  (the title) in your code and you don't say where you want it to appear.  in the box with example 1 ? Above the line? Below the line? ...

Comment: Yes, in the box with example 1. So I get something like: 
Example 1.1 bla bla bla (all onside the box), then rest of body as usual.

Comment: you should have put that in the question:-) but `\fbox{\textbf{Example~\thesection.\theexample}~#1}%` should do what you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{example}
\counterwithin{example}{section}

\newenvironment{example}[1][]{%
    \refstepcounter{example}%
    \par\vspace{5pt}%
    \noindent\fbox{\textbf{Example \theexample #1}}%
    \hrulefill\par}%
   {\par\noindent\hrulefill\vrule}

\begin{document}

\section{First section}
Some introductory text\dots
\begin{example}[: Hello World]
    \begin{equation}
        f(x)=\frac{x}{1+x^2}
    \end{equation}
\end{example}

\end{document}
```